# Regex (Javascript) for parsing email with firstname.lastname.randomnumber@email.com

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, email-parsing

I've scoured all the other threads about this but there's a unique aspect to my parsing format that I can't get past. I'm trying to parse an email address with a standard format as follows - **firstname.lastname.#####@email.com** i.e 'john.smith.12345@email.com'

I want to return any alpha characters before the numeric sequence - 'john smith' (or all names before the .12345 in case people have multiple names).

Right now, I've worked out the regex to `(^[A-Za-z]+\.+[A-Za-z]+)` but that returns 'john.smith' which isn't the end of the world since I can split it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't the end of the world"? You can match the format and split capture group 1 on a dot `^([A-Za-z]+(?:\.[A-Za-z]+)*)\.\d+@[^\s@]+` https://regex101.com/r/ymtghe/1

Comment: To add on to the comment above, it is not possible to have repeating capture groups in RegEx. So you can match a (reasonable) fixed number of dot separated names, but if the number of dot separated names is unbounded, then you must first capture the entire dot-separated string of names, then split on the dot (or use a global regex on this first match).

Comment: @zr0gravity7 thanks, I'm still very new to regex. The number of names wouldn't be unbounded, maybe 3 names total. I was trying to figure out how to recognize the number pattern at the end to bound the names in front.

Answer (score 1):

*Click on the code blocks below to try them out.*

If you only have two or three dot-separated names before the numbers, you can hardcode the group alternatives:

[`(?:([A-Za-z]+)\.([A-Za-z]+)|([A-Za-z]+)\.([A-Za-z]+)\.([A-Za-z]+))\.\d+@[^\s@]+`](https://regex101.com/r/yVTu8Z/1)

Here we use a non-capturing group to enclose the alternatives.

For one, two, or three dot-separated names, the pattern is similar (albeit a bit messier).

---

Another approach would be to wrap some of the preceding dot + capturing group sections with an optional non-capturing group.

[`([A-Za-z]+)\.([A-Za-z]+)(?:\.([A-Za-z]+))?\.\d+@[^\s@]+`](https://regex101.com/r/2KHFbN/1)

This enables a more concise expression of 1-3 dot-separated names as:

[`([A-Za-z]+)(?:\.([A-Za-z]+))?(?:\.([A-Za-z]+))?\.\d+@[^\s@]+`](https://regex101.com/r/G5nFi0/1)